# Metro Area - Geographics

Tags: geographics

I have given the following list of European cities and I would like to have the area (surface or metropolitan, I do not care much). For example, the surface area of Paris is 105.4 km². Is there a way to extract this information from Mathematica?

Thanks in advance.

```
{Entity["City", {"Brussels", "Brussels", "Belgium"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Antwerp", "Antwerp", "Belgium"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Marseille", "ProvenceAlpesCoteDAzur", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Lyon", "RhoneAlpes", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Toulouse", "MidiPyrenees", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Nice", "ProvenceAlpesCoteDAzur", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Madrid", "Madrid", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Valencia", "Valencia", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Seville", "Seville", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Zaragoza", "Zaragoza", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Malaga", "Malaga", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Murcia", "Murcia", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"LasPalmas", "LasPalmas", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Palma", "Balears", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bilbao", "Vizcaya", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Cordoba", "Cordoba", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Alicante", "Alacant", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Valladolid", "Valladolid", "Spain"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Lisbon", "Lisboa", "Portugal"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Dublin", "Dublin", "Ireland"}], 
 Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Birmingham", "Birmingham", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Leeds", "Leeds", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Glasgow", "GlasgowCity", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Sheffield", "Sheffield", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bradford", "Bradford", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Manchester", "Manchester", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Liverpool", "Liverpool", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Edinburgh", "Edinburgh", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bristol", "Bristol", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Croydon", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Leicester", "Leicester", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Coventry", "Coventry", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Doncaster", "Doncaster", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Caerdydd", "Cardiff", "UnitedKingdom"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Amsterdam", "NoordHolland", "Netherlands"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Rotterdam", "ZuidHolland", "Netherlands"}], 
 Entity["City", {"TheHague", "ZuidHolland", "Netherlands"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Utrecht", "Utrecht", "Netherlands"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Rome", "Lazio", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Milan", "Lombardy", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Naples", "Campania", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Turin", "Piemonte", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Palermo", "Sicily", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Genoa", "Liguria", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bologna", "EmiliaRomagna", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Florence", "Toscana", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bari", "Apulia", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Catania", "Sicily", "Italy"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Zurich", "Zurich", "Switzerland"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Vienna", "Vienna", "Austria"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Hamburg", "Hamburg", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Munich", "Bavaria", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Cologne", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Frankfurt", "Hesse", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Stuttgart", "BadenWurttemberg", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Dusseldorf", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Essen", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Dortmund", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bremen", "Bremen", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Dresden", "Saxony", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Hanover", "LowerSaxony", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Leipzig", "Saxony", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Nuremberg", "Bavaria", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Duisburg", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bochum", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Wuppertal", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bielefeld", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Bonn", "NorthRhineWestphalia", "Germany"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Mannheim", "BadenWurttemberg", "Germany"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 12 of the 73 cities in the list `cities`, we can get the area using [GeoArea](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoArea.html):

```
Quiet @ DeleteMissing[
  Transpose[
    {CommonName @ cities, 
     GeoArea @ cities, 
     GeoArea[cities, UnitSystem -> "Metric"]}], 
  1, 1] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `cities` set to the list above this retrieves the Area property for each city. Unfortunately, the result is `Missing["NotAvailable"]` for all of them.

```
#["Area"] & /@ cities
```

Other properties are available

```
#["Population"] & /@ cities
```

Comment: This is very inefficient code, each application in the map is another call

Comment: @M.R. Yes. Much more efficient to retrieve in a single call `EntityValue[cities, "Area"]`.